# Finding probability, Uniform distribution

Tags: probability

What is the probability P(X>Y) given that X,Y are Uniformly distributed between [0,1]?

Answer (score 3):

Draw the square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ and the region $X>Y$ to *see* the answer.

Comment: if that so then it will be conditional probability, which is not.
if I would solve it the way you suggested above, I have to choose X Or Y before calculating.
if I choose X first the probability would be X.
if i choose Y first the probability would be 1-Y.

Comment: @TarekAbed One way is to integrate over all possible choices of $X$. What Emanuele did is, she showed you how to visually see it - the square is a set of all possible choices for $(X,Y)$ with each region being as likely an occurrence as its area (because of the uniform distribution for both $X$ and $Y$). So of all possible choices, you need the proportion where $X>Y$, as she indicated in the answer -- it is exactly 1/2...

Answer (score 1):

A more general approach is based on symmetry -- since $X,Y$ have the same distribution and $\mathbb{P}[X=Y] = 0$ (here, because both are continuous random variables), any outcome $(x,y)$ where $x>y$ is just as likely as the outcome $(y,x)$, so $X>Y$ exactly half the time.

Note that this is independent of distribution - as long as $\mathbb{P}[X=Y] = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are *independent*, Let $Z=X-Y$, Then were looking for $P(Z>0)$. To obtain the distribution of $Z$, you can convolve $X$ by $-Y$. The result will be a triange in the range $-1<x<1$. Then it it is obvious to see that $P(Z>0)=0.5$.

Comment: That  might work, I will try, thanks a lot.